# InfiniDB ERROR 168 (HY000): Cannot execute the statement. DBRM is read only

Tags: infinidb

I have following version of InfiniDB.

> Server version: 5.1.39 MySQL Embedded / Calpont InfiniDB Enterprise
>   3.2.0-2 GA (Commercial)

I am getting following error when I execute `insert/update/delete query`.

> ERROR 168 (HY000): Cannot execute the statement. DBRM is read only.

I restarted `infinidb` many times but the same error appears.

please help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 4):

I recently had the same problem and here are three steps that I did:

- `/usr/local/mariadb/columnstore/bin/dbrmctl status`
- `/usr/local/mariadb/columnstore/bin/dbrmctl readwrite`
- `/usr/local/mariadb/columnstore/bin/dbrmctl reload`

Answer (score 0):

Answering this for other folks who face the same problem..

There are a couple of things you can try:

(1) Restart the service, using `service infinidb restart`

(2) If the error continues, use the calpont command console `cc` and do a `startSystem`

Watch the `crit.log`, `error.log` files under `/var/log/Calpont/` for errors...